# python multiprocessing fastq function

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am a new user of mutliprocessing module in Python3. 
I have 2 fastq files (forward and reverse) and I want to process forward/reverse couple of reads. For this, from forward read, I get the corresponding reverse and apply a function with multiple arguments on the couple. So far, I've done it sequentially on 1 thread, which is quite long for huge files. Now, I would like to improve speed by parallelising the function application, so I create chunk of the forward file and apply function to each chunk using multiprocessing. Here is the code:

```
def chunk_itr(iterator, chunk_size):
    """
    Function to split fastq file into smallest files for faster processing
    From biopython solutions
    """
    entry = True
    while entry:
        chunk = []
        while len(chunk) < chunk_size:
            try:
                entry = next(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                entry = None
            if entry is None:
                break
            chunk.append(entry)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk


def chunk_fastq(f_fastq, chunkSize, path2out):
    rec_itr = SeqIO.parse(open(f_fastq), "fastq")
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path2out, "chunk_files"))
    dir_out = os.path.join(path2out, "chunk_files")
    base = os.path.basename(f_fastq)
    fname = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunk_itr(rec_itr, chunkSize)):
        out_chunk_name = os.path.join(dir_out, "{0}_chunk{1}.fastq".format(fname, i))
        with open(out_chunk_name, "w") as handle:
            SeqIO.write(chunk, handle, "fastq")

def testmulti(fwd_chunk, rev_idx):
    fwd_idx = SeqIO.index(fwd_chunk, "fastq")
    for i in fwd_idx:
        print(i, rev_idx[i])

pathfwd = "path/to/forward_file"
f_rev = "path/to/rev_fastq"

def main():
    rev_idx = SeqIO.index(f_rev, "fastq")
    chunk_fastq(pathfwd, 1000, path2chunk)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(path2chunk)]

# sequential
    for i in files:
        testmulti(i, rev_idx)

# parallel process
    processes = []
    for i in files:
        proc = mp.Process(target=testmulti, args=(i, rev_idx,))
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

The sequential approach works fine but the parallel one crash with the following error:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 28, in testmulti
    print(i, rev_idx[i])
  File "test.py", line 28, in testmulti
    print(i, rev_idx[i])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 417, in __getitem__
    record = self._proxy.get(self._offsets[key])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 417, in __getitem__
    record = self._proxy.get(self._offsets[key])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/_index.py", line 69, in get
    return self._parse(StringIO(_bytes_to_string(self.get_raw(offset))))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/_index.py", line 69, in get
    return self._parse(StringIO(_bytes_to_string(self.get_raw(offset))))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/_index.py", line 664, in get_raw
    raise ValueError("Problem with quality section")
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/_index.py", line 642, in get_raw
    raise ValueError("Premature end of file in seq section")
ValueError: Problem with quality section
ValueError: Premature end of file in seq section
```

From the Index class description in biopython, it seems there is an issue with the file format/structure
I double checked the input files and there are no error (and it works with the sequential approach).
My guess so far:

1. using Process like this is not a good option (I also tried pool.starmap, but without success)
2. since the f_rev is indexed once and then each process try to use it in parallel, there is a conflict

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: So you're saying that if you run `for f in files: fwd_idx = SeqIO.index(f, "fastq")` you don't get any errors as above?

Comment: I forgot to mention it in my original post, but yes
`for f in files:
    fwd_idx = SeqIO.index(f, "fastq")`
works fine

Comment: I find that very unlikely. Especially considering that I cannot repeat your error using the same multiprocessing approach on my own list of local fastq files.

Comment: do you also iterate over chunked forward fastq and then iterate over forward reads and looking for their mate in the indexed reverse file?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. In your code above at no point are you chunking *after* you read in the files? So assuming that your sequential code is reading the same "chunked" forward fastqs as the multiprocessing code, then it shouldn't make a difference where my files come from, it's just about proving that files opened sequentially are the same as when opened in parallel.

Comment: If you are manually chunking the `fastq` files somewhere and not showing that code here, then that is almost certainly where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Files are chunked following the biopython example: https://biopython.org/wiki/Split_large_file
1. forward files are chunked
2. reverse file is indexed
3. function is applied to each of the forward chunk in parallel
When the function is applied file by file (sequential), everything works well, but when multiprocessing is used, an error is generated

Comment: So if you run that code **exactly** as shown above, you get this error? Because I am afraid that with my own fastq I simply cannot replicate this error. Interestingly it seems the error is actually occurring during when trying to retrieve the sequence from the reverse index, rather than when trying to create a new index on the chunked file.

Comment: yes, with this exact code, I got the error. Indeed, from my interpretation of the error and of the get_raw class of the index function, the error could come from the reverse index interrogation by many parallel processes. 
I made a try and add a try/except conditions in the test_multi function: the except allows seeing reads that are not get by the function. In this case, no error is shown but many reads are not treated but perfectly fine in terms of format

Comment: I don't believe there should be any theoretical issue with many processes reading that same file repeatedly, and as I say I cannot replicate this error locally, but how many processes (i.e. chunk files) do you have, and how big is your reverse fastq?

Comment: for the test, the original files (forward/reverse) contain 1248 reads and forward file is chunked in 2 subfiles with a chunk size of 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I am still not 100% sure on the cause of the error, but after increasing the size of my fastq files I was able to replicate it.

It definitely has to do with the reverse index object created with `SeqIO.index` however I'm struggling to fully grasp what exactly that looks like from the source code as there is a lot of inheritance going on. I *suspect* that it is something to do with passing an open file-handle object to the child processes, but again I'm not well-versed enough in that side of things to guarantee it.

However I can successfully prevent the error. The solution involves moving your creation of the reverse index to the child process. I don't see any good reason not to either, the whole point of the `SeqIO.Index` method is that it creates a low-memory index rather than reading the whole file into memory, so creating one per-child process shouldn't be excessively expensive.

```
def testmulti(fwd_chunk, rev):
    rev_idx = SeqIO.index(rev, "fastq")
    fwd_idx = SeqIO.index(fwd_chunk, "fastq")
    for i in fwd_idx:
        print(i, rev_idx[i])

pathfwd = "path/to/forward_file"
f_rev = "path/to/rev_fastq"

def main():
    chunk_fastq(pathfwd, 1000, path2chunk)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(path2chunk)]

# sequential
    for i in files:
        testmulti(i, f_rev)

# parallel process
    processes = []
    for i in files:
        proc = mp.Process(target=testmulti, args=(i, f_rev,))
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: Indeed, I guess indexing reverse file for each chunked forward file shouldn't take so long. Thank you for this answer that solves the error!